# How to use Twitter API?

Tags: twitter

I want to use twitter api without authentication.
Is it possible?
For example, I am going to get the user profile for certain user.
Can I get his user profile without authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User authentication is mandatory. You also need to create a customer account and use the authentication for that.

You will also need to deal with api rate limiting by adding a small sleep time of around 60 seconds.

You can use this [link](https://github.com/gautamaggarwal1989/tweet_puller) to see some working code.

Comment: Then could you explain how twitter bot can work?
Do they work with authentication?
I think bots are working without authentication

Comment: They might be using scraping or multiple user accounts. It was possible earlier to use twitter apis without authentication but not anymore. These apis can use user accounts, can't they? Fake ones, created just for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

All Twitter API calls require the use of OAuth and a registered application with consumer key and token. They also require HTTPS.

A small number of API endpoints can be called without the use of a user context ("application-only" authentication). You *can* call the users/show.json endpoint with application-only authentication using a bearer token and no user context, but that will only work for public Twitter profiles, not protected ones.